# High Client Network Utilization Accessing File Share

Tags: network-share, wireshark

When users try to access specific folders within our file server, their computer will sometimes lock up and stop responding. These folders have images that average 200KB in size. I've duplicated the issue on my PC while watching resource monitor and wireshark. When duplicating the issue, my network utilization will go to 100% on my client PC. Wireshark will show the following in a continuous loop (hundreds per second):

```
TCP - 1514 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
TCP - 1514 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
TCP - 1514 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
TCP - 54 49423 > microsoft-ds [ACK] Seq=671955 Ack=(varies) Win=(varies) Len=0
SMB2 - 918 Read Response
```

Picture shown here:
[image: http://imgur.com/pzVsbvZ]

Server details:
Windows Server 2008
No resource contentions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the computers are trying to view thumbnails for the pictures. I think you stop this by deleting a hidden thumbs.db file and setting a group policy rule to prevent Windows from recreating it.

Comment: Thank you for your post. We ended up Enabling 'Turn off the caching of thumbnails in hidden thumbs.db files' in Group Policy for the specific users. This seems to have fixed the issue.